# jQuery File Upload validation Serverside vs. / and Clientside

Tags: php, jquery, validation, symfony, file-upload

i've got a question regarding the blueimp jquery file upload and its validation.

I know that this file upload library gives me the opportunity to validate the added files with the validate.js file by configuring the fileupload as the following:

```
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: uploadRoute
   /* acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 3000000, // 3 MB
    // The minimum allowed file size in bytes:
    minFileSize: undefined, // No minimal file size
    // The limit of files to be uploaded:
    maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
    // Limit upload size with one request to 20 MB
    limitMultiFileUploadSize: 20000000 // 20 MB*/
});
```

This validation would happen in the front end, so js can be disabled and as i read it is not supported on older versions of browsers, e.g Internet Explorer 8/9.
Therefore, i now 'just' implemented a server side check of the extension, size etc. within my file upload handler class.

Would you recommend me to use in addition to the server side check also the 'front end check' with javascript that the jquery file upload provides ? Or is the traffic caused by a server side e.g. extension check so small that there are no - let's call it - 'traffic risks' .. ?

Regards

Comment: From the viewpoint of user-friendliness I would recommend the client side checks, combined with clear error messages about why the uploaded file doesn't meet the requirements (and what the user can do to meet them).

Comment: Hi FWrnr , the server side check is done via ajax so the user does not need to wait for the error response. I just meant related to server traffic, would it be better to add the additional front end check (which returns the same errors as the server check) just to reduce the server traffic ?

Comment: The amount of client and server traffic depends on the number of (invalid) files uploaded, so checking client side could help keeping the traffic down. If your users use more modern browsers than IE8/9 I would implement the client side checks as it is easily available in blueimp.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But i think that even if i implement client side check, it will also be validated on the server side, just a nice to have feature for me then the client side check. Closed ~ :)